# Can I play a PS4 game on a PC, as long as I own a PS4?

Tags: ps4, bloodborne

I'm going to be away from my house for nearly a month and I really adore the game bloodborne and it'll be boring where I'm going, so I want something to do. I can't take the console with me obviously and remote play won't work from the distance. So I was wondering if it was possible to tell the computer to let me access bloodborne on a PC because I already own a PS4.

Does Sony offer such a service?

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can play on your pc via Remote Play, however you need good upload speed and the PS4 needs to be turned on (or in sleep mode) during the whole time.

> Before using this application, you'll need to do the following on your PS4™ system.
>
> Enable Remote Play. Select  (Settings) > [Remote Play Connection Settings], and then select the checkbox for [Enable Remote Play].
>
> Activate the system as your primary PS4™ system. Select  (Settings) > [PlayStation Network/Account Management] > [Activate as Your Primary PS4] > [Activate].
>
> To start Remote Play while your PS4™ system is in rest mode, select  (Settings) > [Power Save Settings] > [Set Features Available in Rest Mode]. Then select the checkboxes for [Stay Connected to the Internet] and [Enable Turning On PS4 from Network].

You also need to download the Software from the [Source](https://remoteplay.dl.playstation.net/remoteplay/lang/en/index.html)

Comment: should also add that you need the software from the source link. just from your answer it's not entirely evident

Comment: As I said in the question, I doubt remote play will work from the distance.

Comment: @DanielCann Well, it does work, it just requires rather good internet. and since the PS4 is a closed system, there really isn't another way